# Will Cassandra be useful for this scenerio

Tags: cassandra, cassandra-2.1, nosql

I have around 10 Million names, combination of about 5 files each consisting of 2 million names and there are 100s of users. Each user comes with a file which has 1Million numbers.

I need to process these 1 million numbers against 2 million names and generate the values and show the values with names to the User.

Will cassandra be a good choice to make?

Currently I'm using SQL with RoR but it's quite slow in returning the values.

Answer (score 0):

Cassandra is a no-sql database and not rdbms. 
So, if you don't know, then there is no joins in cassandra.

So, if your problem is slow returning data because of IO, then definately cassandra is a good choice.

However, if your result is coming slow because of join, then cassandra cannot help you.
Because, like i said, there is no join in cassandra.

Now coming to your requirement.

It needs more information to frame opinion for that, like, 
when do you want to process data to create value (as batch, on the fly).

How many data records you want to pull and show to user at a time, etc.